# Increase size of embedded image in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page. There is a base64 encoded image in it. I am planning on writing a javascript to increase the size of the image and content on the page. So everything on the page will appear bigger. I am able to increase the font size but not sure about the embedded image.

Comment: You can change the image height and width. But still, is there a compelling reason to do this? Most browsers allow the user to do this with `[Ctrl]+[+]`/`[Ctrl]+[-]` or `[Ctrl]+[scroll]`.

Comment: You want to do it in plain JavaScript, or using jQuery?

Comment: I agree with Bryan.  This function is built into most browsers.

Comment: I have to agree with Bryan on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
<img id="myImage" src="" />
```

Then you can do it like this:

```
$('#myImage').attr({
    width: 150,     // new width
    height: 150     // new height
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just adjust the css for that image or the attributes. Use either height or width, just not both so they scale properly.

Jquery:

```
$("img").css("width","150px");
```

I may be confused but don't all modern browsers support Ctrl + scroll to zoom?

Answer (score 0):

With images referenced by URL, you can change height and width (either the HTML attributes or CSS styles) and the browser will resize the image.  I imagine it will work the same with an embedded image.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is available in most modern browsers, and as such it is unnecessary to duplicate it using client-side scripts. Consider simply informing the user that most browsers have text size controls built in (so that they may use this tool on other sites as well).